# How to sum entries of series for the same index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

So I managed to get the following series from the famous Census data set.

```
STNAME                    
Alabama               37       658466
                      49       412992
                      45       334811
Alaska                71       291826
                      76        97581
                      85        88995
Arizona               106     3817117
                      109      980263
                      110      375770
```

Data type is pandas.core.series.Series

I'm trying to add the last column (population) entries for each state, so that I get

```
STNAME                    
Alabama               1406269
Alaska                478402
Arizona               5173150
```

Thanks!

Comment: df.sum(level=0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas groupby feature.

```
df.groupby(level=0)["population"].sum()
```